# How can I make two overlapping DIVs keep responsive look?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to make two overlapping DIVs keep responsive look, but I'm getting tangled up with the CSS. Could someone guide me a bit? Thanks in advance...

[image: it should look like this]

```css
.div1-interesado,
.div1-interesado img {
  border-radius: 0 0 6rem 0;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: translateY(-1.2rem);
}

.div2-interesado {
  border-radius: 0 6rem 0 6rem;
  background-color: #005677;
  color: #fff !important;
  transform: translatex(-15rem);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" />

<section class="section-primary bg-white">
<div class="row col-md-10">
    <div class="col col-md-5 div1-interesado">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt="img medico" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col div2-interesado">
        <div class="col col-md-9 pull-right">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-9 offset-2">
                <h2 class="titulo-interesado">¿Interesado?</h2>
                <div class="exp-separator-new">
                    <div class="exp-separator-inner-new"></div>
                </div>
                <p><strong>Solicitá tu DEMO llenando el formulario con todos los datos y qué sector se desempeña tu empresa.</strong></p>
                <a href="{{ route('contacto') }}" class="text-uppercase btn boton-new-der boton-blanco"> Solicitá tu demo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise to explain what exactly "keep the responsive look" means. We can't guess what's in your head.

Comment: Also, you seem to be using Bootstrap. Please tag your version.

Comment: Also also, no element should have both `row` and `col-` on it, and columns shouldn't be nested without rows between.

Comment: I mean it looks the same no matter the screen size (currently it resizes and loses the original proportions and positions). I'm using B4